# Facebook page post share count per user

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to recreate a Facebook page tab application similar to this one: https://www.facebook.com/andrewchristian/app_118098318208381

Up to now, using FQL, I plan on fetching user data (if the user liked/commented on a post) *and display a list with an order based on their activity*. It will be a cron running once or twice a day. The only thing I'm missing is a way to know if the user has shared any of the page's posts.

I've been digging around in the [FQL tables](http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/FQL%3astream) (the link is for the stream table) for any clues but I cannot find anything to work with. Has anyone done something similar? Any other ideas on how I can fetch such information? This has to work as "per user", I'm not not interested in the total count of shares on a post.

P.S.: If there is something that counts a user's total likes/comments/shares on a Facebook Page, I'd really like to know about that as it would make my life much easier, I'm open to any suggestion!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _“and give them some credit for interacting with the page”_ – [Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#integration): _“You must not incentivize users to use (or gate content behind the use of) Facebook social channels, or imply that an incentive is directly tied to the use of our channels.”_

Comment: @CBroe That is so true, I did not mean it that way, so I edited the question by _italiating_ the changed part so that others can undestand what we are talking about. Still the problem remains and the rest is a "Terms of use" issue. Thanks for the heads up!